# Are ASR and PAR approaches commonly used in Europe?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, eu, surveillance, par

How common are [ASR and PAR approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance_radar_approach) these days? Are they still practiced anywhere in Europe?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I changed "SRA" to "ASR" because I believe that's the usual abbreviation but if it really should be SRA then of course please rollback my change or edit it again.

Comment: Yes, they exist. No, they are not common.